# How to refresh/modify Meta for facebook?

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, share

I cannot find any documentation on how to solve this since it is an issue that should not exist.
I just made a website and it is hosted on godaddy at the moment.
When I shared it on facebook in a private converation, there was no image in the preview box and it said: website under construction

So I simply had forgotton to change the meta and the title.  I changed it to have a meta image, a title, and a description and when I saved and refreshed it, it still says the same thing.

Over and over, the same words that exist nowhere in my code appear in the website preview when I share it in a conversation with facebook... I would love to understand this if someone could explain.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make sure that page has the correct [OG tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)
2. Use [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to force FB to clear cache, login required.